# Embed ForEach statement inside different ForEach on remote computer

Tags: powershell, remote-access

As always, new to powershell and trying to self-teach myself. Thank you all in advance:

We have a logon script that auto-sets the registry to OUR homepage. When we build computers, we put the logon script inside the C:\Users\Default\%Appdata%\roaming....\startup\ folder. That way any new user that logs on gets the bat file put into their %AppData% folder, and their homepage is auto set.

We recently built a new server and due to some issues, we need to change our homepage URL, therefore needing to change the logon.bat file on all the computers for all user profiles.

---

This script I found on here works perfectly, but only on the local computer it is running on:

```
$source = '\\ITE00463866\Applications\_Layer1_Installs\TS Sector\firstlogon.txt'
$profilesfolder = 'c:\users\'
$excluded_profiles = @( 'All Users', 'Default User', 'Default.migrated', 'Public', 'DefaultAppPool', 'cdwuser', '.NET v4.5 Classic', '.NET v4.5')
$profiles = get-childitem $profilesfolder -Directory -force | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notin $excluded_profiles }
$targetfolder = "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    $destination = $profilesfolder + $profile + $targetfolder
    If ( $(Try { Test-Path $destination.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) {

        copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    Else {

       New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
       copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    }
```

---

I have been trying to add the above ForEach statement INSIDE of a Get-Content | FOREACH($PC in $Computers){....} statement but get all these ODD issues and it only effects the local machine running the script on. For instance, taking every folder in my System32 folder and creating a user named whatever the System32 folder was named, then putting the logon.bat inside of all those %AppData% folders...

```
 $source = '\\ITE00463866\Applications\_Layer1_Installs\TS Sector\firstlogon.txt'
$list = "\\ITE00463866\Applications\_Layer1_Installs\TS Sector\test.txt"
$computers = gc $list

foreach($pc in $computers){

$targetfolder = "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
$excluded_profiles = @( 'Administrator', 'All Users', 'Default User', 'Default.migrated', 'Public', 'DefaultAppPool', 'cdwuser', '.NET v4.5 Classic', '.NET v4.5')
$profiles = get-childitem $profilesfolder -Directory -force | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notin $excluded_profiles }
$profilesfolder = 'c:\users\'

foreach ($profile in $profiles) {

    $destination = $profilesfolder + $profile + $targetfolder
       if ( $(Try { Test-Path $destination.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) {

       #If folder Startup folder is found for profile, add file to destionation, force overwrite
        copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    Else {

       #If folder is NOT found, create folder and move file to destination
        New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
        copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    }
    }
```

---

How do I combine the two scripts to:
For each computer in my list, look in all the user profiles and for each profile (excluding the ones mentioned) add the new logon.bat

Answer (score 0):

If the script u have posted at the top works for you and as long as winrm is configured in ur environment, you can enclose it inside a scriptblock like below:

```
$scriptblock = {
    $source = '\\ITE00463866\Applications\_Layer1_Installs\TS Sector\firstlogon.txt'
    $profilesfolder = 'c:\users\'
    $excluded_profiles = @( 'All Users', 'Default User', 'Default.migrated', 'Public', 'DefaultAppPool', 'cdwuser', '.NET v4.5 Classic', '.NET v4.5')
    $profiles = get-childitem $profilesfolder -Directory -force | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notin $excluded_profiles }
    $targetfolder = "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

    foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    $destination = $profilesfolder + $profile + $targetfolder
    If ( $(Try { Test-Path $destination.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) {

        copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    Else {

        New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
        copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    }
}
```

And then use ur foreach loop like so:

```
$list = "\\ITE00463866\Applications\_Layer1_Installs\TS Sector\test.txt"
$computers = gc $list

foreach($pc in $computers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sid, however, yes our WinRM is not configured for running a script block.. Halts  with the WinRM error. I have asked our network tech if there were any work arounds or to gain an exception...

Answer (score 0):

Asked one of our principal programmers and he corrected my original script without needing to add a scipt block to it. Thank you for 1st suggestion!

Here is the final script that worked!

```
$source = '\\ITE00463866\Applications\_Layer1_Installs\TS Sector\firstlogon.bat'
$list = "\\ITE00463866\Applications\_Layer1_Installs\TS Sector\computers.txt"
$computers = gc $list

foreach($pc in $computers){

$targetfolder = "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
$excluded_profiles = @( 'Administrator', 'All Users', 'Default User', 'Default.migrated', 'Public', 'DefaultAppPool', 'cdwuser', '.NET v4.5 Classic', '.NET v4.5')
$profilesfolder = '\\' + $pc + '\c$\users\'
$profiles = get-childitem $profilesfolder -Directory -force | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notin $excluded_profiles }


foreach ($profile in $profiles) {

    $destination = $profilesfolder + $profile + $targetfolder
       if ( $(Try { Test-Path $destination.trim() } Catch { $false }) ) {

       #If folder Startup folder is found for profile, add file to destionation, force overwrite
        copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    Else {

       #If folder is NOT found, create folder and move file to destination
        New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
        copy-item -path $source -destination $destination -Force -Verbose
        }
    }
    }
```